# How to locate Menu item inside a div and span with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to locate the menu item `Actions` drop down.

Screenshot of Inspector:

[image]

```cs
// driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".actionButtonRoot")).Click();
// driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
// driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("new")).Click();
//driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@ng_string='SDE_ACTIONS']")).Click();
//driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'ACTIONS')]")).Click();
//driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='text']")).Click();
//driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='actionList']")).Click();
//driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='actionButtonRoot']")).Click();
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
//wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("(/html/body/div/xrx-grid-advance/xrx-grid-actions/ng-form/div[1]/div[1]"))).Click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@ClassName='actionButtonRoot']::div")));
//Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li//span[text()='SDE_ACTIONS']")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SelectElement oSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@ClassName='actionButtonRoot']")));
oSelect.SelectByIndex(1);
Console.Write("End Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.actionButtonRoot >span.text[ng-string='SDE-ACTIONS']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='actionButtonRoot']/span[@class='text' and text()='Actions']"))).Click();
  ```